# how to always get the correct link when it is clicked on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If any of the links below is clicked on the class of "i" tag and the whole of the "span" tag will be logged to the console including the entire "a" itself.

My problem is each time I click on any one of the links below sometimes the information logged to the console is "undefined" like the link does not exist.

How do I get it to always log the right information each time it is clicked on.(thus it should log the "" tag,the class of the "" tag and the "" tag

```
<div id="postbox-mood" class="ps-dropdown__menu ps-dropdown__menu--moods ps-js-postbox-mood" style="display:none">
  <a class="mood-list" id="postbox-mood-1" href="javascript:" data-option-value="1" data-option-display-value="joyful">
    <i class="ps-emoticon ps-emo-1"></i><span>joyful</span>
  </a>
  <a class="mood-list" id="postbox-mood-2" href="javascript:" data-option-value="2" data-option-display-value="meh">
    <i class="ps-emoticon ps-emo-2"></i><span>meh</span>
  </a>
  <a class="mood-list" id="postbox-mood-3" href="javascript:" data-option-value="3" data-option-display-value="love">
    <i class="ps-emoticon ps-emo-3"></i><span>love</span>
  </a>
  <a class="mood-list" id="postbox-mood-4" href="javascript:" data-option-value="4" data-option-display-value="flattered">
    <i class="ps-emoticon ps-emo-4"></i><span>flattered</span>
  </a>
  <a class="mood-list" id="postbox-mood-5" href="javascript:" data-option-value="5" data-option-display-value="crazy">
    <i class="ps-emoticon ps-emo-5"></i><span>crazy</span>
  </a>
  <a class="mood-list" id="postbox-mood-6" href="javascript:" data-option-value="6" data-option-display-value="cool">
    <i class="ps-emoticon ps-emo-6"></i><span>cool</span>
  </a>
  <a class="mood-list" id="postbox-mood-7" href="javascript:" data-option-value="7" data-option-display-value="tired">
    <i class="ps-emoticon ps-emo-7"></i><span>tired</span>
  </a>
  <a class="mood-list" id="postbox-mood-8" href="javascript:" data-option-value="8" data-option-display-value="confused">
    <i class="ps-emoticon ps-emo-8"></i><span>confused</span>
  </a>
  <a class="mood-list" id="postbox-mood-9" href="javascript:" data-option-value="9" data-option-display-value="speechless">
    <i class="ps-emoticon ps-emo-9"></i><span>speechless</span>
  </a>
  <a class="mood-list" id="postbox-mood-10" href="javascript:" data-option-value="10" data-option-display-value="confident">
    <i class="ps-emoticon ps-emo-10"></i><span>confident</span>
  </a>
  <a class="mood-list" id="postbox-mood-11" href="javascript:" data-option-value="11" data-option-display-value="relaxed">
    <i class="ps-emoticon ps-emo-11"></i><span>relaxed</span>
  </a>
  <a class="mood-list" id="postbox-mood-12" href="javascript:" data-option-value="12" data-option-display-value="strong">
    <i class="ps-emoticon ps-emo-12"></i><span>strong</span>
  </a>
  <a class="mood-list" id="postbox-mood-13" href="javascript:" data-option-value="13" data-option-display-value="happy">
    <i class="ps-emoticon ps-emo-13"></i><span>happy</span>
  </a>
  <a class="mood-list" id="postbox-mood-14" href="javascript:" data-option-value="14" data-option-display-value="angry">
    <i class="ps-emoticon ps-emo-14"></i><span>angry</span>
  </a>
  <a class="mood-list" id="postbox-mood-15" href="javascript:" data-option-value="15" data-option-display-value="scared">
    <i class="ps-emoticon ps-emo-15"></i><span>scared</span>
  </a>
  <a class="mood-list" id="postbox-mood-16" href="javascript:" data-option-value="16" data-option-display-value="sick">
    <i class="ps-emoticon ps-emo-16"></i><span>sick</span>
  </a>
  <a class="mood-list" id="postbox-mood-17" href="javascript:" data-option-value="17" data-option-display-value="sad">
    <i class="ps-emoticon ps-emo-17"></i><span>sad</span>
  </a>
  <a class="mood-list" id="postbox-mood-18" href="javascript:" data-option-value="18" data-option-display-value="blessed">
    <i class="ps-emoticon ps-emo-18"></i><span>blessed</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

// javascript for handling clicks on the above html links

```
$(".mood-list").click(function(e){
   // get the appropriate link that was 
   // clicked and store it in the variable
   // mood
   var mood =  e.target;
    //sometimes when a particular link is clicked this 
   // will log as "undefined"
    console.log(mood);
//find the icon and get it's class    
var icon = $(mood).find("i");
    if(icon != "null" || icon != "undefined"){
   // find the "<i></i>" tag and get the class  
   icon = $(icon).attr("class");

     //sometimes when a particular link is clicked this 
   // will also log as "undefined"  
    console.log(icon);
    }
 var span = $(mood).find("span")[0];        
   if(span != "null" || span != "undefined"){
     //find the span element and gets html
    //sometimes when a particular link is clicked this 
   // will also log as "undefined"  
console.log(span);
   }

});
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: I think the issue is your value comparisons. You should not be comparing to the string values `"null"` and `"undefined"`, but rather the *actual* `null` and `undefined` values. Or, more simply, `if ($(mood).find("i").length) { ... }` and `if ($(mood).find("span").length) { ... }`

Comment: On a side note, `myVar != null` and `myVar != undefined` are actually the same check, since you are comparing coercive equality, and `null` and `undefined` are coercively equal.

Comment: @mhodges ,thanks alot but that will only solve the comparison issue. With or without the comparison the issue of the undefined being logged will still persist . My issue is i want to get the class of the "<i>" tag , the entire "span" tag and the entire "a" tag logged to the console each time any one of the links is clicked

Comment: @Abcaha Check my answer down below and see if that works for you

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is your value comparisons. You should not be comparing to the string values `"null"` and `"undefined"`, but rather the actual `null` and `undefined` values. However, in this case, since jQuery returns a list (even if no elements were found), `if ($(mood).find("i").length) { ... }` and `if ($(mood).find("span").length) { ... }`

This will ensure your "found" and "not found" checks will be accurate, which means you will not be trying to find child elements (i.e. `.find("i")` or `.find("span")`) on elements that didn't exist in the first place.

Here's a quick example of how this would work:

```js
$(".mood-list").on("click", function () {
  var $trigger = $(this);
  var $icon = $trigger.find("i"); // will return a jQuery list of items (list.length === 0 means not found)
  var $span = $trigger.find("span"); // will return a jQuery list of items (list.length === 0 means not found)
  console.log($trigger.get(0));
  if ($icon.length) {
    let iconClass = $icon.attr("class");
    console.log(iconClass);
  }
  else {
    console.log("icon not found");
  }
  if ($span.length) {
    console.log($span.html());
  }
  else {
    console.log("span not found");
  }
});
```

```css
.mood-list {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="postbox-mood" class="ps-dropdown__menu ps-dropdown__menu--moods ps-js-postbox-mood">
  <a class="mood-list" id="postbox-mood-1" href="javascript:" data-option-value="1" data-option-display-value="joyful">
    <i class="ps-emoticon ps-emo-1"></i><span>joyful</span>
  </a>
  <a class="mood-list" id="postbox-mood-2" href="javascript:" data-option-value="2" data-option-display-value="meh">
    <i class="ps-emoticon ps-emo-2"></i><span>meh</span>
  </a>
  <a class="mood-list" id="postbox-mood-3" href="javascript:" data-option-value="3" data-option-display-value="love">
    <i class="ps-emoticon ps-emo-3"></i><span>love</span>
  </a>
  <a class="mood-list" id="postbox-mood-4" href="javascript:" data-option-value="4" data-option-display-value="flattered">
    <i class="ps-emoticon ps-emo-4"></i><span>flattered</span>
  </a>
  <a class="mood-list" id="postbox-mood-5" href="javascript:" data-option-value="5" data-option-display-value="crazy">
    <i class="ps-emoticon ps-emo-5"></i><span>crazy</span>
  </a>
  <a class="mood-list" id="postbox-mood-6" href="javascript:" data-option-value="6" data-option-display-value="cool">
    <i class="ps-emoticon ps-emo-6"></i><span>cool</span>
  </a>
  <a class="mood-list" id="postbox-mood-7" href="javascript:" data-option-value="7" data-option-display-value="tired">
    <i class="ps-emoticon ps-emo-7"></i><span>tired</span>
  </a>
  <a class="mood-list" id="postbox-mood-8" href="javascript:" data-option-value="8" data-option-display-value="confused">
    <i class="ps-emoticon ps-emo-8"></i><span>confused</span>
  </a>
  <a class="mood-list" id="postbox-mood-9" href="javascript:" data-option-value="9" data-option-display-value="speechless">
    <i class="ps-emoticon ps-emo-9"></i><span>speechless</span>
  </a>
  <a class="mood-list" id="postbox-mood-10" href="javascript:" data-option-value="10" data-option-display-value="confident">
    <i class="ps-emoticon ps-emo-10"></i><span>confident</span>
  </a>
  <a class="mood-list" id="postbox-mood-11" href="javascript:" data-option-value="11" data-option-display-value="relaxed">
    <i class="ps-emoticon ps-emo-11"></i><span>relaxed</span>
  </a>
  <a class="mood-list" id="postbox-mood-12" href="javascript:" data-option-value="12" data-option-display-value="strong">
    <i class="ps-emoticon ps-emo-12"></i><span>strong</span>
  </a>
  <a class="mood-list" id="postbox-mood-13" href="javascript:" data-option-value="13" data-option-display-value="happy">
    <i class="ps-emoticon ps-emo-13"></i><span>happy</span>
  </a>
  <a class="mood-list" id="postbox-mood-14" href="javascript:" data-option-value="14" data-option-display-value="angry">
    <i class="ps-emoticon ps-emo-14"></i><span>angry</span>
  </a>
  <a class="mood-list" id="postbox-mood-15" href="javascript:" data-option-value="15" data-option-display-value="scared">
    <i class="ps-emoticon ps-emo-15"></i><span>scared</span>
  </a>
  <a class="mood-list" id="postbox-mood-16" href="javascript:" data-option-value="16" data-option-display-value="sick">
    <i class="ps-emoticon ps-emo-16"></i><span>sick</span>
  </a>
  <a class="mood-list" id="postbox-mood-17" href="javascript:" data-option-value="17" data-option-display-value="sad">
    <i class="ps-emoticon ps-emo-17"></i><span>sad</span>
  </a>
  <a class="mood-list" id="postbox-mood-18" href="javascript:" data-option-value="18" data-option-display-value="blessed">
    <i class="ps-emoticon ps-emo-18"></i><span>blessed</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: @Abcaha Great `:)` glad I could help. Does this help clarify why your original code was not working?

Comment: @Abcaha Also, please be sure to mark my answer as accepted if my solution ended up working for you. =)